# In notepad I cannot insert a character at the far left of this line that mixes hebrew characters with comma and quotes, when on LTR mode

Tags: windows, notepad, right-to-left

here is the file

http://www.zen76171.zen.co.uk/a.c

`אהב","אהבו"`

Call this **Image A**

[image]

You see the cursor over there.

Hebrew is a right to left language so the left and right arrow keys behave a bit differently as you move through it.

The strange thing is that if I put the cursor where you see it there, on the far left.  Then if I hit a character e.g. double quote, then I get this

[image]

Now, say I open the file again, so look back to ImageA.  Then I try a different character, e.g. the letter 'p' then I get this

[image]

Now I have found as indicated in the title, a bit of a workaround, which is if I put the file in right to left mode. (ctrl with right shift)  then I can add the quote to the correct position and then putting the file into left to right mode the quote is fine there.

But i'm curious if it's possible to do it purely from left to right mode, and if not, then why. Left to right is purely a presentation issue, and right to left mode shouldn't be more functional on a technical level. So what, if anything, am I doing wrong when in left to right mode that I can't insert that quote?  Or is there perhaps a bug in left to right mode?

Comment: Does it help if you press Ctrl+Shift to switch the text field's overall direction to RTL?

Comment: @einpoklum yeah as mentioned in my question, RTL does enable me to put the quote in there, and it is the workaround that i've used  even when I wrote the question, but it isn't answering the question of why it isn't letting me insert the character in LTR mode.

Comment: What happens if you press the 'End' key, then type in the quote?

Comment: @einpoklum I linked to the file it's not very hard for you to try your suggestion. It doesn't work, I get a quote on the far right when I do that.

Comment: short answer is try putting the cursor to the right of the aleph of ahav, and then hit double quote, that seems to work. a big question though would be what is going on?

Comment: note- a suggested edit suggested removing notepad from the title. Not a good idea, since other software might not be identical, and it's a bit risky to talk generally about something so fidgety, and notepad is general and useful enough. The same principle may likely be applied to other programs.

Answer (score 0):

You have your text

Identify a block of hebrew, the start and end of it

[image]

Sometimes you can't even click to the point where you want the quote.

The issue seems to be to do with the idea that you have a block (1+) characters that are LTR followed by a block that are RTL characters, e.t.c. alternating. And the issue seems to be a kind of philosphical question of whether point A and point B are the beginning/end of that block.  Or whether they relate to the previous and next block.  If they relate to the previous and next block then you get the funny results.  Point B would end a previous block, which in LTR mode is at point A. And Point A would begin the next block, which in LTR mode is at point B. So you can get this wrapping effect. And what happens is any english character typed at point A appears at point B, and any hebrew character typed at point B appears at point A.

One may find they can't click on point A, or can't click on point B. Well, then if you want point A, you can try clicking point B, and vice versa. And you may find that a char typed there ends up on the other point which is where you want it.

Also it's worth writing blocks of hebrew and english and watching the cursor move through them as you tap the left and right arrow keys. So you can get some idea of where the beginning and end of blocks are.

Often it's more about the beginning and end of the block than the beginning and end of the line..

Also as far as what distinguishes LTR mode from RTL mode.. In both cases english goes left to right and hebrew right to left. But in LTR mode if you have adjacent blocks i.e. a block of hebrew a block of english a block of hebrew e.t.c.  or a block of english then a block of hebrew then a block of english, the blocks will go from LTR in LTR mode. And RTL in RTL mode. In notepad you also get an alignment to suit it, though some programs e.g. visual studio class file putting data in a list, will order the blocks like that, detecting the hebrew, doing RTL, but still aligning it all to the left. It's still an RTL mode.

Also if all your words are hebrew and the only blocks of english are punctuation marks, then if you use RTL mode then there may be less of an issue, because in RTL mode there's no question that end of any block of hebrew characters, will be adjacent with the next block of hebrew characters.